"Dataform encountered an error: Unexpected property "type", or property value type of "string" is incorrect." using @dataform/cli
I'm working on a Dataform project using the @dataform/cli (https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/use-dataform-cli) package. I want to run the dataform run --dry-run to check my final SQL. I every got the same error:
Dataform encountered an error: Unexpected property "type", or property value type of "string" is incorrect.
ReferenceError: Unexpected property "type", or property value type of "string" is incorrect.

I can compile my project without errors (dataform compile), but with dataform run --dry-run, I'm getting stuck.
Can anyone know what the problem is?

Maybe post a minimal representation of the SQLX that you are trying to compile/run/dry-run.  Perhaps if we looked at that we might be able to spot something?

Hi @Lvi, Could you check this document and this GitHub ? Let me know if this helped you or not.

Hi guys! Thanks for sharing these links, but the answer given by @var0hub solved my problem.

I found the solution, I ran this command dataform init-creds and later it generated a .df-credentials.json file in my project directory like this:
{
"projectId": "project",
"location": "location"
}

When you run the command you will be prompted to choose these options:
$ dataform init-creds

[1] US (default)
[2] EU
[3] other

Enter the location of your datasets [1, 2, 3]: 2

[1] ADC (default)
[2] JSON Key

Do you wish to use Application Default Credentials or JSON Key [1/2]: 1
Enter your billing project ID:
> 

I hope this helps!

Thank very much @var0hub! When I created a new credentials with this command, the command start to work!
